# In django 2.2. select_related field is not working? How to Fix it

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I tried to join two tables in Django orm one is sample 1 and another one is sample 2 table. I used select_related functionality. but It's throwing an error on how to fix it.

**Models.py**

```
class Sample1( models.Model )
   a = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
   b = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
   sample3 = models.ForeignKey(Sample3, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   sample4 = models.ForeignKey(Sample4, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Sample2( modes.Model )
   sample1= models.ForeignKey( Sample1,on_delete=models.CASCADE )
   created = models.DateTimeField()
   updated = models.DateTimeField()
```

**Views.py**

```
def sample_data(request):
    sampl_data = Sample1.objects.select_related("sample2__sample1").filter( created__lte = '2018-11-01 
    00:00:00-05:00', updated__gte = '2013-10-31 00:00:00-05:00')
    print(samp1_data)
```

When I tried to run this program It's show this error **django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'sample2'. Choices are: sample3, sample4**

Comment: your `Sample1` Model don't have any `sample2` field

Answer (score 1):

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is used only to follow relationship on Foreign key ( in your case sample3 and sample4 )

> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships,
> selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.

Performance optimizations of what you are trying to achieve can be done using [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)